# GCE says I exceeded my CPU quota, well, I did not. What to do?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have two VMs, one with 2 CPU and another with 1 CPU, but, when I "click to deploy" a mongodb, I get the message: "Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 8.0"

3 + 5 = 8 ...

What should I do? Is there a CPU count cache or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you in a free trial account ? if so, you are limited to 8 vCPUs. From what you mentioned, you are already using 3 vCPUs..so you should have 5 available.

When launching MongoDB click-to-deploy, make sure you are using `n1-standard-1` or `n1-standard-2` machine types and lower the MongoDB server nodes (default is 2 from what I see)

Also, please be advised that while the deployment is in progress, there is another machine that gets instantiated (a deployment coordinator), which takes an additional vCPU..so take that into account

You can check your current CPU quota in `Developers Console > Compute Engine > Quotas`

Comment: Well, I just gave up on "click-to-deploy" for now. Created the instances manually and it works fine. Thanks, Marius!